# What is the best approximate of points on a sphere?

Tags: optimization, euclidean-geometry

I have a unit radius sphere with a set $S$ of $n$ points on it.  How can I find a map $f:S\to \mathbb{R}^4$ which minimizes
$$\sum_{x,y\in S} \bigg( d_{\text{geodesic}} (x,y)^{2} - d(f(x),f(y))^{2}\bigg)^2$$

$d_{\text{geodesic}}(x,y)$ is the [length of the shortest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Examples) on the sphere from $x$ to $y$, and $d(f(x),f(y))$ is the Euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}^4$.$\hspace{-0.03 in}\big)$

Comment: ... append a 0 to their coordinate tuples. $\;$

Comment: No, the original distances are geometric not Euclidean! I am not sure about the name maybe geographical distance!

Comment: Do you have in mind a particular measure of how well they're preserved? $\:$ When I did something like that, I used sum-of-squares-of-logs-of-ratios-of-distances (over the choice of pairs of distinct points), but I've [also seen](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/maxmin3/) a measure which is equivalent to replacing that "sum" with "max" (where the original metric is [a discrete metric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteMetric.html)). $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need SSE. It seems there are multiple solutions with minimum error, the final solution depends on the initial values for the new dimension. I programmed it in GAMS and tried different solvers to minimize the squared errors, but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: Are the "squared errors" just $\big(\hspace{-0.02 in}d_{\hspace{.03 in}0\hspace{-0.02 in}}(x,\hspace{-0.03 in}y)\hspace{-0.03 in}-\hspace{-0.03 in}d_{\hspace{.02 in}1\hspace{-0.02 in}}(x,\hspace{-0.03 in}y)\hspace{-0.04 in}\big)^2\hspace{-0.04 in}$, or a type of [relative error](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RelativeError.html)? $\;$

Comment: min $\sum_i delta^2$ such that $d_0^2(x,y)-d_1^2(x,y)=\delta_i$

Comment: If relative formulation makes it easier?

Comment: I have no reason to think the relative formulation would make it any easier. $\;$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31613/discussion-between-remo-and-ricky-demer).